# Rescheduling Backups: Is there a way to do it?

Tags: 13.10, backup

Is there a way to reschedule the backup to another day and keep it like that with the pre-installed backup program?  Because the day I have it on (I do weekly backups) doesn't work for me and I have to do them after being reminded a thousand times before doing one.  If this matters, I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scheduled tasks`tool (from the software center) to create a cron job to run  `rsync` to copy whatever you want to wherever you want it at whatever time you want it copied. Since rsync only copies new or changed files, you could have it run every day and never notice it. The command could be as simple as

```
 rsync -a --delete ~/ /backup-drive/daily.backup
```

[Here's a nice tutorial.](http://www.howtogeek.com/135533/how-to-use-rsync-to-backup-your-data-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I think exists is to disable weekly backups and wait until the day and time that works and run the first weekly backup from that time and day.